# How to call messagebox from tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a Tkinter-based GUI in Python and I have a problem: messagebox does not appear when I'm getting data from the Entry widget. How can I solve it?

```
from tkinter import *
import random


win = Tk()
win.title("Sample")
win.resizable(False, False)
win.configure(bg="#767676")

def game():
    entry = Entry_field.get()
    days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Sunday", "Saturday"]
    randomise = random.choice(days)
    messagebox.showinfo("Ответ", randomise)

Label_field = Label(win, text="Choose your day!", font=("outrun", 10, "bold"))
Label_field.grid(row=0, column=0)

Notification_Label = Label(win, text="Enter your name here", font=("montserrat", 10, "bold"), bg="#EF9A9A")
Notification_Label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

Entry_field = Entry(win, width=30)
Entry_field.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button_field = Button(win, text="Press", command=game)
Button_field.grid(row=1, column=2)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to put this line at the top: `import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox`

Comment: Put this at the top of your code and everything will work fine: `from tkinter import messagebox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the `showinfo` function from the `tkinter.messagebox` module, but haven't imported it. You need to add `import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox` or `from tkinter import messagebox` line to the top of your code. Here is the full fixed code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
import random


win = Tk()
win.title("Sample")
win.resizable(False, False)
win.configure(bg="#767676")

def game():
    entry = Entry_field.get()
    days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Sunday", "Saturday"]
    randomise = random.choice(days)
    messagebox.showinfo("Ответ", randomise)

Label_field = Label(win, text="Choose your day!", font=("outrun", 10, "bold"))
Label_field.grid(row=0, column=0)

Notification_Label = Label(win, text="Enter your name here", font=("montserrat", 10, "bold"), bg="#EF9A9A")
Notification_Label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

Entry_field = Entry(win, width=30)
Entry_field.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button_field = Button(win, text="Press", command=game)
Button_field.grid(row=1, column=2)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think using `from tkinter import messagebox` is a better way.